# Modular development in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, modular-design

How do I add a module and manage their dependency in Xcode using swift?

Is there a way like I could done it by a few clicks in Android Studio?

What exactly is the keyword I should search for?

Or should I even need to do this in iOS development?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Key words "embedded framework".
[Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2435/_index.html) you can find instruction.
In couple words: File->New Target (Or Project)-> iOS Framework -> Select parentTarget.